# Como crear un trigger que modifique algunos registros de una tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Necesitó crear un trigger que resuelva lo siguiente:
Tengo dos tablas, la primera se llama **“documentos_aclaratorios_contratistas”** la cual tiene las columnas

- id
- nombreDocumento
- idContratista
- docCargado ---> default 0
- eliminado
- fechaSistema

y la segunda tabla se llama **“archivos_documentos_aclaratorios”** con las columnas

- id
- idContratista
- archivo
- eliminado
- fechaSistema

el trigger debe modificar el campo **docCargado** de la primera tabla pasándolo de su valor por defecto que es 0 a 1, cuando detecte que se agregaron registros en la segunda tabla, pero debe tomar el **idContratista** de los registros agregados en la segunda tabla y modificar los registros de la primera tabla que tengan el mismo **idContratista**.
De antemano, gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a la pregunta que realice es la siguiente:
Para crear el trigger que resuelva lo que necesitas, puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Crear el trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_docCargado
AFTER INSERT ON archivos_documentos_aclaratorios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE documentos_aclaratorios_contratistas
    SET docCargado = 1
    WHERE idContratista = NEW.idContratista;
END;
```

2. Explicación del trigger:

- `CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_docCargado`: crea el trigger y le da un nombre.
- `AFTER INSERT ON archivos_documentos_aclaratorios`: indica que el trigger se activará después de que se inserten registros en la tabla "archivos_documentos_aclaratorios".
- `FOR EACH ROW`: indica que el trigger se ejecutará para cada registro insertado en la tabla.
- `BEGIN`: indica el inicio del cuerpo del trigger.
- `UPDATE documentos_aclaratorios_contratistas`: indica que se actualizarán registros en la tabla "documentos_aclaratorios_contratistas".
- `SET docCargado = 1`: establece el valor del campo "docCargado" en 1.
- `WHERE idContratista = NEW.idContratista`: indica que se actualizarán los registros que tengan el mismo valor de "idContratista" que el registro insertado en la tabla "archivos_documentos_aclaratorios".
- `END`: indica el fin del cuerpo del trigger.

Con este trigger, cada vez que se inserte un registro en la tabla "archivos_documentos_aclaratorios", se actualizarán los registros correspondientes en la tabla "documentos_aclaratorios_contratistas", estableciendo el valor del campo "docCargado" en 1.